References for Atiyah-Bott fixed point theorem and localization theorem
I'm familiar with Atiyah-Singer index theorem and its proof using pseudosifferential operator and heat kernel approach.
I have some references about the index theorem, but they only explain about the fixed point theorem breifly, not in detail.
Are there good references or notes about the proofs possible generalizations of Atiyah-Bott fixed point theorem and localization theorem?
This note written by Getzler is highly useful to know how it is going on, but I hope there are more details about it.
